# Plotly: Overwrite chart's data with new data

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am trying to  understand the example given in the link https://plotly.com/python/v3/sending-data-to-charts/#overwrite-chart-data-with-new-data

Error message ***The plotly.plotly module is deprecated,
please install the chart-studio package and use the
chart_studio.plotly module instead.***

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
data = Data([ Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[3, 4]) ])
plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='my plot')
```

then, modified the code to below but getting more and more errors. ***"'Data' is not defined"***

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs.scattergl import *

data = Data([ Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[3, 4]) ])
plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='my plot')
```

my objective to **overwrite** the plot with new df data set.

Comment: Do not use star imports. Either `module.Data` other `from module import Data` will help you.

Comment: oops..I am new to plotly; I didn't get what u mean.